# Check if multiple textfields are empty jQuery

Tags: jquery

This might be simple but I'm having difficulties here. I'm running the required attribute through all fields of `.um_frm` and then checking if all fields are not empty. My problem is that instead of checking ALL fields, it passes through even if a single field is filled. How do I make sure that all fields are filled?

```
$('#um_ok').on( 'click', function() {
      $('.um_frm').attr('required','required'); 
      var value=$.trim($(".um_frm").val()); 
      if(value.length === 0){
          //proceed...
      }
});
```

I also tried this but was not suiccessful

```
$('#um_ok').on( 'click', function() {
       $('.um_frm').attr('required','required'); 
       if($.trim($(".um_frm").val()) === ""){
           //proceed...
       }
 });
```

Comment: Please make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a filter to see if any field is blank (length *not* truthy, i.e. 0, hence the `!`):

```
$('#um_ok').on( 'click', function() {
      $('.um_frm').attr('required','required'); 

      var anyBlank = $(".um_frm").filter(function(){
          return !$.trim($(this).val()).length;
      }).length; 

      // If not any blanks...
      if(!anyBlank){
          //proceed...
      }
});
```

**Update: (thanks @George)**

As `required` is a genuine HTML element property and not just an attribute, you should use `prop` (which can then take the more readable Boolean value as its on/off state):

```
      $('.um_frm').prop('required', true);
```

This has the advantage of creating the cleaner `required` attribute with no value (instead of `required="required"` etc).

Comment: +1 An up-vote for an answer that actually deserves one. Make a note about using `.prop()` to set properties like `required` (:

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I have no reference except [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5876747/1612146). If you think logically, we don't care about the required *attribute*, we want to change the *property* because that is what causes required's behaviour.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie The code does not run when I use `prop`.

Comment: @George: hmm. Is that a browser compatibility thing?

Comment: I tried this using the latest version of chrome (v38)

Comment: @Fergoso: I would like to get a definitive result on the `required` `prop` vs `attr` that was suggested. Do you have some sample HTML or a JSFiddle I can test with?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Here's the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8LLLucoe/) . Wired... I just created this and it works. Not sure what is the difference between mine and the example fiddle. But I got mine to work so all good for the moment. Let's see in future... Thanks again.

Comment: @Fergoso: Yep, it looks like `prop` is the way to go with required. Also creates the cleaner `required` attribute with no value as a bonus. I'd have to see your actual page to see why it failed there, but I'm now confident enough to suggest it as a guideline again :)

Answer (score 1):

**WORKING [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6e0csn3n/1/)**

Use following

```
$('#um_ok').on('click', function () {
    var status = true;
    $('.um_frm').each(function () {
        if ($.trim($(this).val()) == '') {
            status = false;
        }
    });
    if (status) {
        alert("all r ok");
    } else {
        alert("sumthng missing");
    }
});
```

Comment: This will alert/action once for every blank entry (quite annoying)... Better to maybe return an overall result and then report it?

Comment: Better now (and I formatted it for you), but I would suggest using string values for a `boolean` state is not an appropriate thing to encourage. Just use true & false :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie did. thnx

Comment: +1: Got there in the end :) I still prefer `filter` to `each`, but the end result is the same).

Comment: @Fergoso  , it should ! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will do

```
var left_blank =$('#um_ok').on( 'click', function() {
                    $(".um_frm").filter(function () {
                      return !$.trim($(this).val()).length;
                  }).length;
               });
if(!left_blank){
    //proceed
}
```

Comment: Wait, how does it answer question?

Comment: You should either add the appropriate `if` statement afterwards, or explain to the OP what is going on here. As it stands, this code does nothing except evaluate a `true` or `false` value...

Comment: You are not actually checking for blanks... you are checking for any *non-blanks* at the moment.

Comment: I missed it actually :)

Comment: FYI zero/non-zero checks can be reduced to truthy/falsy checks (e.g. `!length` rather than `!length > 0`), but then your answer will look exactly like mine :)

Comment: @BlankHead Your `if` statement will be carried out not when the button is clicked, but straight away, and never again. Also you need `left_blank` to have the value of the `length` property you get. You are assigning the jQuery object that you are attaching the handler to.

Comment: Looks like a case on one-too-many edits now. You have now assigned a jQuery selector result (element `#um_ok`) to `left_blank`. :(